# How to act upon error log additions?

Tags: linux, logging, watch, webhooks

Normally I watch logs using `tail -f /the/error.log`, but I normally only act upon them when I hear people complain. I know you can send them to an email address, but email simply sucks. So I rather want the error logs of my server to be sent to a dedicated slack channel.

My question is: how can I watch additions to the error log and catch those additions in a variable so I can send them as json to the slack webhook? I also wonder, what if the error logs is more than one line? I don't want a 20-line error to be sent as 20 separate messages.

All tips are welcome!

Comment: You could use something like [fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) which can collect logs from various sources, filter them, and send them to various destinations.  There is a [slack output plugin](https://github.com/sowawa/fluent-plugin-slack) for fluentd.